# MongoDB is not updating the data

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I have two modules. listingproperties and users' dashboard.

```
function propertyVerification(id){
  listingproperty.propertyVerificationFlag = 1;
  $http.put('/api/listingproperties/' + id, vm.ListingpropertiesService).success(function() {
    listingproperty.propertyVerificationFlag = 1;
    Notification.success('Property flagged successfully');
  }).error(function() {
    Notification.error('Property flagged successfully');
  });
}
```

The above code is users' dashboard controller code. I'm trying to verify listed property by flag value to 1.

This code snippet runs perfectly but it is not reflecting on MongoDB database.

What is the wrong in above code?

Below is my server side code.

```
function ListingpropertiesService($resource) {
 return $resource('/api/listingproperties/:listingpropertyId', {
  listingpropertyId: '@_id'
},  {
     update: {
     method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
}
```

Also,

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
 var listingproperty = req.listingproperty;

 listingproperty = _.extend(listingproperty, req.body);

 listingproperty.save(function (err) {
 if (err) {
   return res.status(400).send({
     message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
   });
 } else {
   res.jsonp(listingproperty);
 }
 });
};
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see any save() or update() or insert() command. Without any of it the data will not persist in the DB.

Comment: Please add the code that is doing the MongoDB persistency on the server side.

Comment: It would be a great help if you can help me with the server controller because I'm new to mean stack.

Comment: Should I write save() or update() in the Listing property server controller or dashboard controller?

Comment: @ShujaAhmed Can you please check the updated question?